# Non-RSPO MB glycerin vs RSPO-MB glycerin

Tags: chemical-engineering

Does non-RSPO-MB glycerin function differently than RSPO-MB glycerin? For example in a cosmetic serum /lotion?

Comment: A good practice is to explicitly explain less common acronyms. Even if readers do not know them and are not experts in the field, they may bring some insights from their own domain of expertise.

Answer (score -2):

No. The RSPO-MB (Roundtable on Sustainable Palm Oil- Mass Balance) certification has nothing to do with the purity or quality of the glycerin. It is a certification of the supply chain for the palm oil which is used to make the glycerin.

Ref: [RSPO Supply Chains](https://rspo.org/certification/supply-chains)